# Mongoose sort by a field in the last element of a nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
[{
  _id: '1',
  logs: [
    {
      createdAt: "2021-04-01",
    },
    {
      createdAt: "2021-04-02",
    },
  ],
},{
  _id: '2',
  logs: [
    {
      createdAt: "2021-04-03",
    },
    {
      createdAt: "2021-04-04",
    },
  ],
}]
```

I want to sort by the `createdAt` of the last element of `logs` in desc order. In this example item `_id:2` should be the first and item `_id:1` should be the second since `2021-04-02` is 'smaller' than `2021-04-04`.

I tried `'logs[logs.length - 1].createdAt': -1` and `'logs.createdAt': -1` but they don't work.

Comment: just try sort by only `{ "logs.createdAt": -1 }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get sorted Object with respect to the last entry in each of the array,

- you need to fetch the last date from the array which can be done using $last operator.
- Next I am adding the field which has the entry of the last createdAt in a new field name - sortField.
- I will sort it according to the sortField.
- I will unset the sortField.

I know there would be better ways to do this, but it should do the job for the time being.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sortField": {
        "$last": "$logs.createdAt"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "sortField": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "sortField"
  }
])
```